# display multiplication table in TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to generate a multiplication table,where the 1st EditText takes the actual number while 2nd EditText takes the actual range of multiplication table. When I run the project , the result is only number *** range..**
can anyone help me in the loop or code below mentioned Or,any alternatives to display the table in `GridLayout` or `TableLayout` rather than `TextView`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiplication_table);
    number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberTable);
    range = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberRange);
    click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
    final String x = range.getText().toString();
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          int   a = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
          int   b = Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());



             for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1 ; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    int res = a * b;
                            result. setText(a +" * " + b + " = " + res);

                }





            }
            return;
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "actual number" and "actual range"? Maybe an example of your desired end result would help

Comment: Can you give some sample input of both EditText and expected result?

Comment: @EthanWilliams- Well.. for example if I have a actual number as 2.. & desired range as 10.. so the loop should be displaying.. the multiplication table of 2 .. as in..
 2 x 1 = 2 to
 2 x 10 = 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling `setText()` for every row, but `setText()` will reset the text of the `TextView`, you might want to use `append()` instead

```
result.setText("");
int a = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());

for(int i = 1 ; i <= b; i++){       
    int res = a * i;
    result.append(a +" * " + i + " = " + res + "\n");       
}
```

or maybe use `StringBuilder`

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 1 ; i <= b; i++){       
    int res = a * i;
    builder.append(a +" * " + i + " = " + res + "\n");      
}

result.setText(builder.toString())
```

Comment: @lelloman- umm.. thankyou for the answer. but still there's some issue.. Actually it should be like 
 2 x 1 = 2
 2 x 2 =4
 2 x 3 = 6.. and so on..
 but its like
 number  * range = value
 range is not being started from 1
 and its displaying same value and outuput such as.. actual number =  and desired range =
 5
 so its displaying  2 * 5 = 10
 same till the loop ends

Comment: ok now i see, i just edited the answer, you should just need one for loop

Comment: @lelloman-Thank you so much for the answer. it worked well !! Could you help me out in another context... As I am trying to develop a simple calculator with basic functionalities. How can I disable the button if the button is pressed without any input in the TextView. Or how can I display error message in the TextView if the button Is pressed without input. Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: nice , you're welcome :) I'm not sure I understood your new problem but here's my 2 cents, to enable or disable a View you can call setEnabled(boolean enabled), to get the input from an EditText call getText().toString(), I think you are using an EditText to get the input right?

Comment: @lelloman-Yup..!! I got it!! Its working well..!! Thankx much.. :)